# Spark: Convert a textfile to Dataframe using case class

Tags: apache-spark

I wanted to convert textfile to dataframe using case class and below is my code. It works till map split where I can see the value using `rdd_metadata_schema.take(1).foreach(arr => print(arr.toList))` but is empty when I check for the dataframe.

```
case class metadata_schema(
                          field_name:String,
                          field_pos:String,
                          field_dataType:String
                                  )
  val rdd_metadata = Spark.sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("textfile")
  val rdd_metadata_schema = rdd_metadata.map(row => row.split('|')).map(field => metadata_schema(field(0), field(1), field(2)))
  val df_metadata = Spark.sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd_metadata_schema,classOf[metadata_schema])

**textfile:**
field1|1-2|String
field2|3|String
```

Everything looks fine to me. I wanted to create df only using case class as the other approach works for me. This is to refresh my skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you do it

```
  case class metadata_schema(
                              field_name:String,
                              field_pos:String,
                              field_dataType:String
                            )
```

Make sure the case class is outside the object.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val rdd_metadata = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file path")
  val rdd_metadata_schema = rdd_metadata.map(row => row.split('|')).map(field => metadata_schema(field(0), field(1), field(2)))

  //you don't need to create using createDataFrame() just toDF is sufficient

  rdd_metadata_schema.toDF().show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
|field_name|field_pos|field_dataType|
+----------+---------+--------------+
|    field1|      1-2|        String|
|    field2|        3|        String|
+----------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: One question here, what is the purpose of having implicits in this logic?

Comment: it is used for implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spark 2, there is an easier way using Dataset:

```
 val revenues = spark
    .read
    .format("csv")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("textfile")
    .as[metadata_schema]
    .toDF()
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this one and it worked. But wanted to try using case class as well.

Comment: You are using a case class in this one too. is the line before the last one:     .as[metadata_schema]. This way you avoid the manual split of each row

Comment: val df_metadata = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").schema(schema).option("delimiter","|").load("textfile")

Comment: The above one worked using StructType. However I tried .as[meta_schema] but get error "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`field_name`' given input columns: [_c0, _c1, _c2];"

Answer (score 1):

When a `case class` is used in `rdd` (as you have done), `schema` is already created using reflection on rdd so you don't have to use `sqlContext` and `schema` to create dataframe.

Just do

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
rdd_metadata_schema.toDF().show(false)
```

and you should get

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
|field_name|field_pos|field_dataType|
+----------+---------+--------------+
|field1    |1-2      |String        |
|field2    |3        |String        |
+----------+---------+--------------+
```

[official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) says so too

> > The Scala interface for Spark SQL supports automatically converting an RDD containing case classes to a DataFrame. The case class defines the schema of the table. The names of the arguments to the case class are read using reflection and become the names of the columns. ...

You can even create `dataset` as

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
rdd_metadata_schema.toDS().show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful